# How to efficiently deal with lists of varying length

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a series of time series of varying length. Numpy's 2D arrays are impractical for this, as all rows (and columns) must be of the same size. My series are stored in a file, one per line. My solution is to read the file line by line the python way and create a python list of numpy 1D arrays

```
series = []
for l in file:
  series.append(numpy.fromstring(l))
```

It's a little bit slower than reading a csv file of the same size with genfromtxt, but not too bad. The bigger problem for me is that I cannot benefit from all the powerful slicing operations of numpy arrays.

Is there a better way in numpy (or panda, although I know nothing about it) to get a series of varying length series? I want to be able to load them from a file easily (bonus points for avoiding the for loop if possible) and have powerful numpy-like slicing capabilities.

Comment: How big of a dataset are you dealing with?  If it is not too large, perhaps you could just make each time series the same length by padding with None.  Then you could use a numpy array of objects.

Comment: `series = [ numpy.fromstring(l) for l in file ]` will be faster than your loop, as you don't have to call `list.append` repeatedly.

Comment: @chepner indeed, thanks. Just ran a test, and it's even faster than the pure numpy version actually where I use genfromtxt! It doesn't solve the problem of slicing though

Comment: @Ben that would work for slicing.